# jsPDF issue with addHtml() and cross-domain images?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, jspdf

I'm using addHtml() to take a "screenshot" of my webpage and save as PDF. The text looks good, however no images are displaying. I'm reading that this might be due to having cross-domain images. Is there a way around this?

According to html2canvas documentation, you can allow cross-domain images by using the 'allowTaint' option: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#available-options

Is there a way to integrate the html2canvas options into my jsPDF function? So far I have:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.addHTML($("#pageContent"), 0, 0, options, function () {
  pdf.save('pageContent.pdf');
});
```

Comment: You could try using `html2canvas` to render the page, then [`getImageData()`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp) to get the image data then store that to the PDF using [`addImage`](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/).

Comment: It looks like when I use addImage() with a sample image, it replaces the original text with that image.. maybe I need to find a way to use it with addHtml(). Also, the image I'm trying to include is served from a cdn.. I don't know if that's part of my issue.

Comment: I did a test with a local image, which worked fine. But the image which is being hosted by cdn shows up blank. This is probably more html2canvas related.. I've read about an 'allowTaint' and 'proxy' option available for cross-domain images, but so far haven't gotten that to work. http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Is this fixed :D